# How to build .jar and .aar artefact for the same source code using Jenkins

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, jenkins

I am currently having a project (Project A) configured in Jenkins which builds a .jar artefact and it is used by web services project (Project B). This project (Project A) consists of common library files; These files are also used by android based applications (Project C).

**Problem:** I am not able to use the jar built in (Project A) in (Project C); Reason (Project C) is built using Android tools while the (Project A) is built using eclipse spring tools and is used by (Project B) which is also built using spring tools. The folder structure and build.scripts vary!!!

**What I have tried:** I created a new Library project (Project D) with the source files in (Project A) using Android studio, Managed to generate a .aar file and added this module as dependency in my android project (Project C). This works!!

**Questions:**

How to achieve the above using Jenkins, i.e. ***A single source repository of my common library files*** should be used to build **.jar as in (Project A)** and also **.aar as in (Project D)** in Jenkins? Greatly appreciate if someone with expertise in build automation can share the build steps to achieve the same.

**EDIT 1:** is there a common folder structure that I can use to build .jar and .aar files which I can use in both eclipse and android studio respectively?

**UPDATE 1:** I managed to create a single repository in git with Android based Folder structure (as compared to the previous eclipse based one) for my common library project (Project A); And Also generated a .jar artifact that is usable in  both (Projects B and C), with some modification to the .gradle files in projects B and C! Still working on the Jenkins Automation part...

I also understand there are changes in the build script (build.gradle) for (Project A) and (Project D); Is it possible to specify Jenkins to use a specific build script for a specific project by retaining a single source repository? *(gradle.build-A for Project A and gradle.build-D for Project D)* any pointers to achieve the same will also be helpful.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I get you correctly, but:
If you build an `.jar` with your jenkins and deploy it to your Nexus, it should be accessible from your Android Studio project like any other dependency. All you would need to take care of is, that your `build.gradle` (on project level) has the Nexus configured as repository (the default is jCenter() I believe).

If you do not run a Nexus or Artifactory or something like that, I guess you just drop your jars in a lib folder. You still can do this with your jar.

Android ARchives (`.aar`) are lot like `.jar` but they take some special resources into account, that a regular `.jar` just don't have (like a manifest for instance).
If your library from project A is plain old Java, I see no reason this should not work (maybe some sort of JDK-version-differences maybe), just include it like any other dependency.

There indeed is a difference between Android an other Java projects.
Android uses android-gradle for building and usually you build Java applications with Maven.
A built `.jar` from Maven is absolutely usable within an android-gradle app, I do this very often.

Comment: You are right, There is a JDK-version difference and also the (Project A) is not a Plain old Java project. I was successful in adding module dependency via .aar; but with .jar there are some bottlenecks!!

Comment: like I said, this should work out as jar just nicely. You may need to elaborate more on your bottlenecks.

Comment: I got it fixed! I just built the common library .jar (Project A) in android studio as java library project {with all dependencies} and this jar is now usable in both spring tools IDE and Android studio IDE projects. The bottlenecks were related to other dependencies and the JDK mismatch. Now, I have it figured out, Thanks!